# How to take a picture with the mac webcam in PNG?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, file-conversion, webcam

Photo Booth saves photos in JPG and I find it a bit tedious to convert from JPG to PNG. [I’m not using Automator anymore for this.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362524/macos-how-to-take-a-picture-from-camera-after-1-minute)

For some reason when I use imagesnap, it can only save in JPG.

So what software program could I use to make my webcam pictures in PNG? There is a Python script written by machine learning researchers that can only accept PNG (see [here](https://github.com/senguptaumd/Background-Matting#getting-started)).

```
imagesnap -h
Capturing image from device "<imagesnap-master 
USAGE: ./imagesnap [options] [filename]
Version: 0.2.5
Captures an image from a video device and saves it in a file.
If no device is specified, the system default will be used.
If no filename is specfied, snapshot.jpg will be used.
JPEG is the only supported output type.
  -h          This help message
  -v          Verbose mode
  -l          List available video devices
  -t x.xx     Take a picture every x.xx seconds
  -q          Quiet mode. Do not output any text
  -w x.xx     Warmup. Delay snapshot x.xx seconds after turning on camera
  -d device   Use named video device
```

Comment: Weirdly enough [this](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/) seems to support more formats

Comment: Yea, I find it weird as well. I just did `brew reinstall imagesnap`, yet I still only get JPEG. That's the reason why I included a screenshot.

Comment: @MelvinRoest  If you're willing to write a script, https://www.life2coding.com/save-opencv-images-jpeg-quality-png-compression/ use opencv library in python. Just give it access to the webcam & it will work.

Comment: If I were you I would try cloning the [repo](https://github.com/rharder/imagesnap) or downloading it from [here](http://www.iharder.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/)

Comment: Fair enough, I could build it myself. It seems like such a simple task that I didn't thought of that.

Comment: Imagesnap only outputs jpg, as written in your screenshot. There is nothing strange about that.

Comment: https://github.com/rharder/imagesnap <-- in that link it says it supports PNG

Comment: It's not really clear what you are looking for here. You know about Automator so you could easily create a workflow to do the conversion. You found `imagesnap` which, when downloaded from Github, supports output to PNG. What else do you need?

Comment: My `imagesnap` doesn't, it says it only supports JPEG when typing `imagesnap -h`. Ideally, I'd have a Photo Booth like application that outputs to PNG.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using PNG for photographs. It's *really* not design for that, and it performs really poorly.

Comment: Apparently the comments were deleted that stated why I needed this. The following machine learning project needs it: https://github.com/senguptaumd/Background-Matting#getting-started -- it's a project that allows you to have a green screen by analyzing a picture of you in it and the same picture without you in it. For each different person it needs a picture. These pictures need to be in PNG. I could do it in other ways, I just find it very strange that there isn't any consumer software out there easily findable by Google that saves to PNG. I thought someone might know.

Answer (score 6):

The version of `imagesnap` distributed through Homebrew (and available on https://github.com/rharder/imagesnap) doesn't support PNG. Apparently support for other formats besides JPG was removed when [QTKit got replaced by AVFoundation](https://github.com/rharder/imagesnap/commit/d1b97226e58eed399bfce061244a4b769223f2be#diff-a6c6bb16daf8f94a92d253529b7c6495).

If you download 0.2.5 directly from http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/ you get a version which also supports other formats.

```
$ ./imagesnap -h
USAGE: ./imagesnap [options] [filename]
Version: 0.2.5
Captures an image from a video device and saves it in a file.
If no device is specified, the system default will be used.
If no filename is specfied, snapshot.jpg will be used.
Supported image types: JPEG, TIFF, PNG, GIF, BMP
  -h          This help message
  -v          Verbose mode
  -l          List available video devices
  -t x.xx     Take a picture every x.xx seconds
  -q          Quiet mode. Do not output any text
  -w x.xx     Warmup. Delay snapshot x.xx seconds after turning on camera
  -d device   Use named video device
```